# PHP - Use API That Only Offers HTML + JS With PHP Script

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have a conversion ***(HTML2PNG)*** I need to automate in a PHP script using a REST API. However, the only example provided on the website was via HTML and JavaScript where one can only upload the HTML file to be ***converted*** in a form.

My **PHP** script already generates **HTML** files in a loop, thus, I'd like to simply pass these generated **HTML** files to the API which then returns the download **URL** of the converted **PNG** file which I know I can use **wget** to retrieve. This is the code as offered by the service.

```
<form action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="conversionform" id="conversionform">
     <p>Local file: <input id="file" name="file" type="file" /></p>
     <p>Target format:
         <select name="targetformat" id="targetformat"">
           <option value="png">PNG</option>
         </select>
     </p>
     <p><input type="button" value="Convert" onclick="convertpdfform()" /></p>
     <p><span id="resulttext">Conversion Results: </span></p>
 </form>
<script src="https://www.aconvert.com/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.aconvert.com/js/jquery.form.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
  });
  function showResponse(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form)  {
    resulttext.innerHTML=responseText;
  }
  function showError(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form)  {
  }
  function convertpdfform() {
    options = {
      success:       showResponse, 
      error:         showError,
      url:       "https://s2.aconvert.com/convert/api-win.php",
    };
    $('#conversionform').ajaxForm(options);
    $('#conversionform').ajaxSubmit(options);
    return false;
  }
</script>
```

**What I've Tried**

- Emailed them to ask for PHP examples and I got ***'there are no PHP examples'*** as response.
- I know **value="png"** is what the API gets to determine the output file.

How can I simply pass the file without using a web browser and still get the download URL of the converted file?

**P:S** - I'm not only using the site because of html2png, they offer tons of other conversion services.

Comment: So you basically want to perform a `multipart/form-data` POST request including a file upload. That can be done using cURL for example.

Comment: @CBroe Please how do I go about that in the scenario I've provided. Just point me in the right direction kindly.

Comment: I would pretty much consider that previous comment to be the “pointer” here already. If you don’t know yet, how to make such a request using cURL in PHP - then this is the point where you should start to do your research and go read up on things.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can create a file based on the HTML code produced by your PHP script and try to emulate the uploading on the form it self. like how web scraping works but simulating the clicks and upload too.
you can definitely do it by looking at the web request. Use Chrome to see the actual request from beginning to end

Comment: Please, I've adjusted the PHP script to put contents of the html code in a file. How do I go about the other aspects of your suggestion?